# How to use BeautifulSoup to parse <p> tags as if they were closed?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Apparently, `<p>` tags only need to be closed when the following tag would be permitted inside a paragraph, but should not be included.

```
# case 1
<div>
<p>Sentence 1.
<span>Interjection!<span>
<p>Sentence 2.
</div>
```

This would end up with two paragraphs (I think), it would be as if one had written:

```
# case 2
<div>
<p>Sentence 1. <span>Interjection!<span></p>
<p>Sentence 2.</p>
</div>
```

In my case, I would like BeautifulSoup to parse the paragraph as whatever the standard prescribes. But in particular, in the example below (case 3), I would want only "Sentence 1.", leaving the header out of it.

```
# case 3
<div>
<p>Sentence 1. 
<h2>Interjection!<h2>
<p>Sentence 2.
</div>
```

Currently, BeautifulSoup *keeps going* parsing (like in case 4), but this is not what I see when I view a site like this online (using chrome).

```
# case 4 (bs4 currently)
<div>
<p>Sentence 1. <h2>Interjection!<h2> <p>Sentence 2.
</div>
</p>
</p>
```

I am using the `html.parser`. Could using a different parser help here?

Comment: Is there a reason why the tags cannot be closed? This potentially opens up a can of worms in the future. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125354/what-are-the-actual-problems-of-not-closing-tags-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: I prefer that the tags were closed, but I didn't write the pages I am working with.

Comment: That's so strange. The HTML parser should be placing the end tags in this order: `<p>Sentence 1. </p> <h2>Interjection!<h2> <p>Sentence 2. </p>` This isn't the first time I've heard of BeautifulSoup not parsing HTML correctly though.

Comment: Using a different parser isn't going to help, because if you used the XML parser, it would just not even parse because the markup isn't well-formed XML, despite being valid HTML.

Comment: have you considered reading the page with selenium and then passing it to beautifull soup? You would be using your browsers render engine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have typo for `<span>` and `<h2>` because it has no closing tag or missing the `/`, if not it will create other empty tag.

And yes using different parser like `lxml` could help fix the structure and the result are same with HTML standard (Chrome).

case 1 input:

```
<div>
<p>Sentence 1.
<span>Interjection!</span>
<p>Sentence 2.
</div>
```

case 1 results, ignoring `<html><body>`:

```
<div>
<p>Sentence 1. <span>Interjection!</span></p>
<p>Sentence 2.</p>
</div>
```

case 2 input

```
<div>
<p>Sentence 1. 
<h2>Interjection!</h2>
<p>Sentence 2.
</div>
```

case 2 result

```
<div>
<p>Sentence 1.</p>
<h2>Interjection!</h2>
<p>Sentence 2.</p>
</div>
```

The different is the `h2` is not wrapped in `p` because it is `block element` or starts on a new line so the parser will stop and close the tag, while `span` is `inline element`.