# Gmail breaking email HTML template layout

Tags: html, email, gmail, digital-signature, html-templates

I'm working with **HTML template** that works on every mail client properly. But in **Gmail**, the layout is breaking.

This is how it looks on **gmail**:

[image: gmail_layout]

And this is how it looks everywhere else:

[image: other_layout]

And here is mycode:

```html
<body>

 <table role="presentation" width="615" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
  style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">

  <tr>
   <td align="center"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" border="0" alt="Name" /></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>

    <br>
    <hr style="height:0.5px" color="#00aaff">

    <div style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">

     <table width="595" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
      style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; line-height: 19px;">
      <tr>
       <td height="10" style="line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <td valign="top">Some lorem ipsum random textum <br /><br /></td>

      <td width="10" style="line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
       <table class="noMobile" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="12" border="0" bgcolor="#f3f3f3">
        <td>
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
          style="font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #333333; line-height: 19px;">
          <tr>
           <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#555555" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Test</b>
            </font><br /><br /><br />
           </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

           <td width="110"><b>[param2]:</b></td>
           <td>[param3]</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><b>[param4]:</b></td>
           <td>[param5]</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" style="color: #00aaff"><br /><br />

            <b>Text line 1<br />Text line 2 <br />Text line 3 <br /> Text line 4. <br />Text line 5 <br />Text line
             6.</b>
           </td>
          </tr>a
         </table>

  </tr>
  </td>

 </table>
 </td>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <hr style="height:0.5px" color="#00aaff">
 <p>test template random text lorem ipsum donesum weirdsum</p>
</body>
```

I've tried everything - includes changing `min-width` or `max-width` by `viewport` but it still broken. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like you are missing a lot of closing HTML tags. This may cause your layout to break. 
 
**See more:**

- [Do browsers automatically insert missing HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26850313)
- [What are the actual problems of not closing tags and attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125354/what-are-the-actual-problems-of-not-closing-tags-and-attributes-in-html)
- [What happens if we don’t add a closing tag?](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/what-happens-if-we-dont-add-a-closing-tag/368401)